# KOMA book class: listoftables increase the space between the number and title of a table

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, scrbook

In my **List of Tables**, the number and title text are too close together sometimes overlapping for wide numbers.

An alert is generated for this (although it doesn't mention the **List of Tables** specifically):

```
Package tocbasic Warning: number width of table toc entries should be increased
!
(tocbasic)                Currently used number width = 25.2507pt,
(tocbasic)                Wanted number separation    = 4.37993pt,
(tocbasic)                Reserved number width       = 25.18501pt on input line 16.
```

Here is a very artifical example where the number of the table is getting over-written by the title

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoftables

\chapter{Twiddle}
\section{Dee}
\appendix
\setcounter{chapter}{22}
\chapter{Tweedle}
\section{Dum}
\begin{table}[htb]
\caption{The is time is 5:21}
\caption{The is time is 5:22}
\caption{The is time is 5:23}
\caption{The is time is 5:24}
\caption{The is time is 5:25}
\caption{The is time is 5:26}
\caption{The is time is 5:27}
\caption{The is time is 5:28}
\caption{The is time is 5:29}
\caption{The is time is 5:30}
\caption{The is time is 5:31}
\caption{The is time is 5:32}
\caption{The is time is 5:33}
\caption{The is time is 5:34}
\caption{The is time is 5:35}
\caption{The is time is 5:36}
\caption{The is time is 5:37}
\caption{The is time is 5:38}
\end{table}


\end{document}enter code here
```

[image]
When this happened in the main **Table of Contents** I was able to adjust the *tocnumwidth* with these commands:

```
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  tocnumwidth=30pt
]{section}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  tocnumwidth=36pt
]{subsection}
```

What is the name (instead of section or subsection) I should use to adjust the *tocnumwidth* for a **List of Tables** and/or indeed a **List of Figures**; or is there a completely different way of doing this?

Also, can someone suggest how I might have found this out by looking at the source or, better still, in the KOMAscript manual

Comment: `\section` and `\subsection` are both section commands. But a table is not a section command. So if you want to change a table entry to the LoT instead of a section entry to the ToC, use `\DeclareTOCStyleEntry` for `table` entries. See the `tocbasic` chapter of the KOMA-Script manual. If you need more help, please show a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964).

Comment: @cabohah Declaring a TOC-style for tables? I can't find any hint in the manual to what you seem to refer to.

Comment: @cabohah OK, so are you suggesting that to fix this requires \CloneTOCEntryStyle to clone the section style (for scrbook), tweak an initial value to adjust spacing and then associate this cloned-style with List of tables?
Or maybe just cloning it to be the default is enough; but then what needs changed to increase the width - is it still \tocnumwidth?

Comment: No, I suggest to use `\DeclareTOCStyleEntry` as explained in the `tocbasic` chapter of the KOMA-Script manual. Cloning is not needed.

Comment: @cabohah OK got it!
Man that is seriously opaque - even with figure 15.1 in the manual; I stared at that for 15.1  minutes before it started to make sense. 
Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 3):

`\RedeclareSectionCommand` cannot be used to configure the `table` entries to the List of Tables. However reading the documentation of `\RedeclareSectionCommand`:

> The different TOC-entry styles also have different additional attributes. You can set them
> directly if you prefix them with `toc`. For example, you can set […] the number width,
> `numwidth`, using `tocnumwidth`. For more TOC-entry style attributes see section 15.3 […]

leads to section 15.3 and attribute `numwidth`. In this section we can find, command `\DeclareTOCStyleEntry` to setup `numwidth`. The command has one optional argument and two mandatory. The first and optional argument is the list of options or attributes. This is the `numwidth=…` we want to set. The second and mandatory argument is the style. For table or figure entries we can just use either `default`, which is the default style KOMA-Script classes use, or a dedicated style, that provides `numwidth`, e.g., `tocline`. The last and also mandatory argument is the entry level, which is `table`. So we would have, e.g., the preamble line:

```
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[numwidth=35pt]{default}{table}
```

to setup the number width attribute `numwidth` of `table` entries using the `default` style (which is `tocline` with `scrbook`) to 35pt.

Adding this to your example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[numwidth=35pt]{default}{table}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoftables

\chapter{Twiddle}
\section{Dee}
\appendix
\setcounter{chapter}{22}
\chapter{Tweedle}
\section{Dum}
\begin{table}[htb]
\caption{The is time is 5:21}
\caption{The is time is 5:22}
\caption{The is time is 5:23}
\caption{The is time is 5:24}
\caption{The is time is 5:25}
\caption{The is time is 5:26}
\caption{The is time is 5:27}
\caption{The is time is 5:28}
\caption{The is time is 5:29}
\caption{The is time is 5:30}
\caption{The is time is 5:31}
\caption{The is time is 5:32}
\caption{The is time is 5:33}
\caption{The is time is 5:34}
\caption{The is time is 5:35}
\caption{The is time is 5:36}
\caption{The is time is 5:37}
\caption{The is time is 5:38}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

results in:

[image]

BTW: Instead of using an explicit `numwidth` you can also use attribute `dynnumwidth`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[dynnumwidth]{default}{table}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoftables

\chapter{Twiddle}
\section{Dee}
\appendix
\setcounter{chapter}{22}
\chapter{Tweedle}
\section{Dum}
\begin{table}[htb]
\caption{The is time is 5:21}
\caption{The is time is 5:22}
\caption{The is time is 5:23}
\caption{The is time is 5:24}
\caption{The is time is 5:25}
\caption{The is time is 5:26}
\caption{The is time is 5:27}
\caption{The is time is 5:28}
\caption{The is time is 5:29}
\caption{The is time is 5:30}
\caption{The is time is 5:31}
\caption{The is time is 5:32}
\caption{The is time is 5:33}
\caption{The is time is 5:34}
\caption{The is time is 5:35}
\caption{The is time is 5:36}
\caption{The is time is 5:37}
\caption{The is time is 5:38}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

After at least **three** LaTeX runs, this results in:

[image]

For documentation of `dynnumwidth` see Table 15.1 in the KOMA-Script manuals.

Insider note: If you want to know the `numwidth` value `dynnumwidth` used, see line

> ```
> \global\@namedef{scr@dte@table@lastmaxnumwidth}{32.66748pt}
> ```

in the `*.aux` file.